# Error when doing inner join with cross cache join

Tags: ignite

I have a studentinfo cache for StudentInfo class and a classinfo cache for ClassInfo,
These two classes are used to do join(Student has an attribute of classId)

With the following code snippet,

```
    SqlFieldsQuery innerJoinSQL = new SqlFieldsQuery(
            "select StudentInfo.studentId, StudentInfo.name, StudentInfo.classId from StudentInfo as a, " +
            "\"class_cache\".ClassInfo as  b where a.classId = b.classId");
cursor = studentCache.query(innerJoinSQL);
for (List data : cursor) {
    System.out.println(String.format("studentId %s, studentName %s, classId %s, className %s", data.get(0), data.get(1), data.get(2), data.get(3)));
}
```

I got following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.cache.CacheException: Failed to parse query: select a.studentId, a.name, a.classId, b.name from StudentInfo a, 'class_cache'.ClassInfo b on a.classId = b.classId
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryTwoStep(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1137)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:732)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor$2.applyx(GridQueryProcessor.java:730)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.lang.IgniteOutClosureX.apply(IgniteOutClosureX.java:36)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.executeQuery(GridQueryProcessor.java:1666)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.GridQueryProcessor.queryTwoStep(GridQueryProcessor.java:730)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:700)
    at ignite.sqlgrid.join.IgniteSQLJoinQueryTest.main(IgniteSQLJoinQueryTest.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECT A.STUDENTID, A.NAME, A.CLASSID, B.NAME FROM STUDENTINFO A, 'class_cache'[*].CLASSINFO B ON A.CLASSID = B.CLASSID "; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select a.studentId, a.name, a.classId, b.name from StudentInfo a, 'class_cache'.ClassInfo b on a.classId = b.classId [42001-191]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:205)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifierWithSchema(Parser.java:3115)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableFilter(Parser.java:1202)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimpleFromPart(Parser.java:1884)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSimple(Parser.java:2032)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectSub(Parser.java:1878)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectUnion(Parser.java:1699)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:1687)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:443)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:315)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:287)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:252)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:560)
    at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:501)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1188)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:73)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:276)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.prepareStatement(IgniteH2Indexing.java:406)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.query.h2.IgniteH2Indexing.queryTwoStep(IgniteH2Indexing.java:1121)
    ... 12 more
```

Can some help where the problem is? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Looks I figured out the problem.
My two pojo(StudentInfo and ClassInfo) for each cache has one same column named `classId`. Looks only one pojo can set index = true with annotation  `@QuerySqlField(index = true)` on the classId field

But I am not sure that Ingite has such constraint. If someone knows, let confirm, thanks!

Comment: Your initial problem was in invalid quoting of cache name.

Comment: invalid? I didn't understand you. Can you explain more? For me, I didn't change the sql but just change the index to false ,and it works.

Comment: I'm not sure what is the actual problem here, but what you described is definitely not true (unless there is some crazy bug). It would be easier to help if you could create a small GitHub project with the test so that anyone can run it and reproduce the behavior.